# Moving average using loop

Tags: r, loops, moving-average, mutate

Here is my dataframe, `IPI_index_wide`:

```
structure(list(time = c("gen. 2019", "febr. 2019", "març 2019", 
"abr. 2019", "maig 2019", "juny 2019"), `Unió Europea` = c(104, 
103.8, 114.4, 105.7, 106.7, 107.9), `Zona Euro` = c(102.7, 102.3, 
112.6, 104, 104.7, 106.3), Alemanya = c(96.3, 99.6, 112.3, 100.6, 
100.7, 103.3), Espanya = c(105.6, 105.7, 112.1, 104, 112.9, 110.4
), França = c(107.2, 104.2, 114.4, 105, 101.6, 108.4), Itàlia = c(101, 
108.2, 116.1, 102.2, 114.2, 110.8)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to add a **new column for each region** (`Unió Europea`, `Zona Euro`, `Alemanya`, `Espanya`, `França`, `Itàlia`) that **calculates the moving average** for the current month and its three previous months. And each of these **new columns should be named as they are now plus `_ma`.**

So far I have tried:

```
ma <- function(x, n=3)
  {stats::filter(x, rep(1,n), sides = 1)/n}  

IPI_index_wide <- IPI_index_wide %>% 
  ma()
```

But it substitues the original columns for the moving average.

Comment: You are applying the ma() function to the whole data frame. You need to use mutate to create a new column if you want to use Tidyverse. Or use $ notation.

Answer (score 2):

For a `dplyr` solution, you can `mutate` `across` all regions:

```r
ma <- function(x, n=3)
{stats::filter(x, rep(1,n), sides = 1)/n}  

library(dplyr)

IPI_index_wide %>%
  mutate(across(-time,
                ma,
                .names = '{.col}_ma'))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 13
#>   time       `Unió Europea` `Zona Euro` Alemanya Espanya França Itàlia
#>   <chr>               <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 gen. 2019            104         103.     96.3    106.   107.   101 
#> 2 febr. 2019           104.        102.     99.6    106.   104.   108.
#> 3 març 2019            114.        113.    112.     112.   114.   116.
#> 4 abr. 2019            106.        104     101.     104    105    102.
#> 5 maig 2019            107.        105.    101.     113.   102.   114.
#> 6 juny 2019            108.        106.    103.     110.   108.   111.
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: `Unió Europea_ma` <dbl>, `Zona Euro_ma` <dbl>,
#> #   Alemanya_ma <dbl>, Espanya_ma <dbl>, França_ma <dbl>, Itàlia_ma <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using only `data.table`.

```r
library(data.table)

# Constructs moving window sizes
window_seq <- function (k, n, partial = TRUE){
  stopifnot(length(k) == 1L, length(n) == 1L)
  if (n > .Machine[["integer.max"]]) {
    stop("n must not be greater than .Machine$integer.max")
  }
  n <- as.integer(n)
  k <- as.integer(k)
  k <- min(k, n)
  k <- max(k, 0L)
  pk <- max(k - 1L, 0L)
  p_seq <- seq_len(pk)
  out <- rep_len(k, n)
  if (partial) {
    out[p_seq] <- p_seq
  }
  else {
    out[p_seq] <- NA_integer_
  }
  out
}

partial_ma <- function(x, n, ...){
  data.table::frollmean(x, n = window_seq(n, length(x)), adaptive = TRUE, ...)
}

setDT(df)
ma_cols <- setdiff(names(df), "time")
ma_cols_new <- paste0(ma_cols, "_ma")
df[, (ma_cols_new) := lapply(.SD, function(x) partial_ma(x, n = 4, align = "right")), 
   .SDcols = ma_cols]
df
#>          time Unió Europea Zona Euro Alemanya Espanya França Itàlia
#> 1:  gen. 2019        104.0     102.7     96.3   105.6  107.2  101.0
#> 2: febr. 2019        103.8     102.3     99.6   105.7  104.2  108.2
#> 3:  març 2019        114.4     112.6    112.3   112.1  114.4  116.1
#> 4:  abr. 2019        105.7     104.0    100.6   104.0  105.0  102.2
#> 5:  maig 2019        106.7     104.7    100.7   112.9  101.6  114.2
#> 6:  juny 2019        107.9     106.3    103.3   110.4  108.4  110.8
#>    Unió Europea_ma Zona Euro_ma Alemanya_ma Espanya_ma França_ma Itàlia_ma
#> 1:         104.000     102.7000     96.3000    105.600    107.20  101.0000
#> 2:         103.900     102.5000     97.9500    105.650    105.70  104.6000
#> 3:         107.400     105.8667    102.7333    107.800    108.60  108.4333
#> 4:         106.975     105.4000    102.2000    106.850    107.70  106.8750
#> 5:         107.650     105.9000    103.3000    108.675    106.30  110.1750
#> 6:         108.675     106.9000    104.2250    109.850    107.35  110.8250
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To keep the NAs for the first 3 months, just use `frollmean()`

```r
df[, (ma_cols_new) := lapply(.SD, function(x) frollmean(x, n = 4, align = "right")), 
   .SDcols = ma_cols]
df
#>          time Unió Europea Zona Euro Alemanya Espanya França Itàlia
#> 1:  gen. 2019        104.0     102.7     96.3   105.6  107.2  101.0
#> 2: febr. 2019        103.8     102.3     99.6   105.7  104.2  108.2
#> 3:  març 2019        114.4     112.6    112.3   112.1  114.4  116.1
#> 4:  abr. 2019        105.7     104.0    100.6   104.0  105.0  102.2
#> 5:  maig 2019        106.7     104.7    100.7   112.9  101.6  114.2
#> 6:  juny 2019        107.9     106.3    103.3   110.4  108.4  110.8
#>    Unió Europea_ma Zona Euro_ma Alemanya_ma Espanya_ma França_ma Itàlia_ma
#> 1:              NA           NA          NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 2:              NA           NA          NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 3:              NA           NA          NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 4:         106.975        105.4     102.200    106.850    107.70   106.875
#> 5:         107.650        105.9     103.300    108.675    106.30   110.175
#> 6:         108.675        106.9     104.225    109.850    107.35   110.825
```